# Function Computation In Simple Type Theory

Tags: logic, homotopy-theory, type-theory, lambda-calculus

I am trying to implement a simple type theory (typed lambda calculus with sums) like the one described in

[Extensional Normalisation and Type-Directed Partial Evaluation for Typed Lambda Calculus with Sums](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/%7Empf23/papers/Types/tdpe.pdf)

I wish to derive the following rule:

$$\begin{array}{c}
\Gamma,x:A\vdash m:C\\
\overline{\Gamma,x:A\vdash\left(\left(\lambda x:A\right).m\right)\left(x\right)\equiv m:C}
\end{array}$$

But the only approach I have thought of, is use the functional computation rule:

$$\begin{array}{c}
\Gamma,x:A\vdash m:C\hspace{1em}\Gamma\vdash a:A\\
\overline{\Gamma\vdash\left(\left(\lambda x:A\right).m\right)\left(a\right)\equiv m\left[a/x\right]:C}
\end{array}$$

together with weakening, to do a proof as follows:

$$ \begin{array}{c}
\Gamma,x:A\vdash m:C\hspace{1em}\hspace{1em}\hspace{1em}\hspace{1em}\\
\underline{\overline{\Gamma,x:A,x:A\vdash m:C}\hspace{1em}\overline{\Gamma,x:A\vdash x:A}}\\
\Gamma,x:A\vdash\left(\left(\lambda x:A\right).m\right)\left(x\right)\equiv m:C
\end{array} $$

But this reasoning involves including the repetition $x:A, x:A$ in the context, which I thought was not allowed (but I could be wrong).

I was hoping somebody could tell me if this is the right approach to proof, or if I am missing something. Another work around would be if the notation $\Gamma, x:A$ were interpreted as $\Gamma$ in the case where the type declaration $x:A$ is already in $\Gamma$.

I know I am focusing on small details, but I want to implement this theory in a computer program, and so I need to set things up very precisely.

Comment: Your proof looks fine to me! Unless you're working with a [linear type system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_logic), duplicating $x$ in the context $\Gamma$ is totally ok ^_^

Comment: Doubling a variable in context is called "weakening". This should be one of the basic rules of deduction given.

Comment: Thank you both for verifying I am on the right track.